# How can I detect extension or shrinkage on window resize?

Tags: jquery, resize

I wonder how can I detect, on window resize, if user extends or shrinks the view port?

One general idea would be this one but I am not sure how to implement it:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var initialWidth = ...;
    var initialHeight = ...;
    var finalWidth = ...;
    var finalHeight = ...;
    if ((initialWidth < finalWidth) || (initialHeight < finalHeight)) { 
        return 'expand'; 
    } else {
        return 'shrink';
    }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it:

```
var initialWidth;
var initialHeight;
$(document).ready(function(){
    initialWidth = $(window).width();
    initialHeight = $(window).height();
})

$(window).resize(function() {

    var finalWidth = $(window).width();
    var finalHeight = $(window).height();
    var result;
    if ((initialWidth < finalWidth) || (initialHeight < finalHeight)) { 
        result = 'expand'; 
    } else {
        result = 'shrink';
    }

    initialWidth = finalWidth;
    initialHeight = finalHeight;

    return result;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will work only for one direction. If I start expand the viewport the function will return 'expand', but when I start shrink the viewport, it will still continue returning 'expand' until it reaches the initial viewport width.

Comment: I got your idea, I have just edited my code, you can try it for your situation